# Loop for array created by comma separated values in mysql query fetching first result only

Tags: php, mysql

I have saved some values as comma separated in table 1 column.

I want to fetch all rows containing values from table 2 where these comma separated values are.

But my current code is fetching only one row with first value.

Tables structure is like below :

**Table 1**

```
id   |  faculties           | another_field
1    |  DFGHFGD1,ERTGDFGE2  | xyzxyzxyz
```

**Table 2**

```
id   |  unique_id   | full_name
1    |  DFGHFGD1    | AAA AAA
2    |  THOGHFGD1   | BBB BBB
3    |  ERTGDFGE2   | CCC CCC
4    |  LLMNBHUH1   | DDD DDD
5    |  HGFGDHHD3   | EEE EEE
6    |  RGDJHFGN4   | FFF FFF
7    |  PLYHTGGD1   | HHH HHH
```

Now I want to fetch both rows with unique_id =  DFGHFGD1 And ERTGDFGE2 in Table 2.

I tried following code. But it is fetching only first value(DFGHFGD1) row.

```
 <?php 
        $faculty ="DFGHFGD1,ERTGDFGE2"; // Fetch with another query for table 1
        $var = explode(",", $faculty );
        ?>
          <ol>
           <?php
             foreach($var as  $value){
             $fquery = "select * from table_2 where unique_id = '$value'";          
             $result = $database->get_results($fquery);
                foreach($result as $data){
            ?> 
                <li><?php echo $data['full_name'];?></li>
            <?php }  ?>
          </ol>
  <?php } ?>
```

**Result should be like**

1. AAA AAA
2. CCC CCC

**But I am Getting only**

1. AAA AAA

Comment: "I have saved some values as comma separated in table 1 column." -- Big mistake! Read ["Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad?r=SearchResults&s=1|192.6363) and normalize the schema.

Comment: Are you sure the `</ol>` is in the right place, should it be outside both the `foreach()` loops?

Comment: @stickybit should I save values in table 1 with comma separate in separate mysql table in rows ?

Comment: @NigelRen I changes place of <ol> and </ol> and tried just now but same result

Comment: @darshan: Yes, exactly.

Comment: @stickybit I have created new table to store id and unique_ids in different row... but when I fetch, till it is returning only first value... loop is not working...

Answer (score 1):

## `<ol>` Tag will be outside of first foreach loop.

### Correct code will be :

```php
<?php 
$faculty ="DFGHFGD1,ERTGDFGE2";
$var = explode(",", $faculty);
?>
<ol>
<?php
foreach($var as $value) {
  $fquery = "select * from `table_2` where `unique_id` = '$value'"; 
  $result = $database->get_results($fquery);
  foreach($result as $data){ ?>
    <li><?php echo $data['full_name']; ?></li>
  <?php 
  } 
}
?></ol>
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged. Please click on [edit] and add some words explaining how your code addresses the question. Thanks